Image Prediction Failed in Flask Backend
I have created a Flask backend that can upload an image through an endpoint and it will predict that image through an image model.
@automatic.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

    model_config = ModelConfig("users/thushara2@gmail.com/automatic/characters.jpg")
    pred = model_config.get_predictions()
    print(pred)
    return "Predicted"

The Prediction process will go through another Python class called ModelConfig, and the image path should be entered as a constructor parameter.
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array


class ModelConfig:
    def __init__(self, image_path):
        self.model = load_model('model_config/model.h5')
        self.image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        self.labels = self.get_labels()
        self.predicted = {}

    @staticmethod
    def get_labels():
        with open("model_config/labels.txt", 'r') as label_file:
            return label_file.read().splitlines()

    @staticmethod
    def sort_contours(contours, method="left-to-right"):
        reverse = False
        i = 0
        if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
            reverse = True
        if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
            i = 1
        bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
        (contours, bounding_boxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, bounding_boxes), key=lambda b: b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

        return contours, bounding_boxes

    def get_predictions(self):
        y, h, x, w = None, None, None, None
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh1, None, iterations=2)
        contours = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
        contours = self.sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")[0]
        # loop over the contours
        for c in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(c) > 10:
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            roi = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            thresh = cv2.threshold(roi, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            thresh = cv2.resize(thresh, (32, 32), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            thresh = thresh.astype("float32") / 255.0
            thresh = np.expand_dims(thresh, axis=-1)
            thresh = thresh.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)

            print("making prediction")
            pred = self.model.predict(thresh) # BUG LINE FOR FLASK 
            print("predicted")
            pred = np.argmax(pred)
            label = self.labels[pred]
            if label in self.predicted:
                self.predicted.update({label: self.predicted[label] + [roi]})
            else:
                self.predicted.update({label: [roi]})
        return self.predicted


When the endpoint is called there is an error message on the line that predicts the image (eg: model.predict(image)) called,
File "D:\Projects\Python\backend\model_config\model_handler.py", line 53, in get_predictions
    pred = self.model.predict(thresh)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Projects\Python\backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 18-37: character maps to <undefined>

but I have created a test file but it doesn't go through such endpoints. It has successfully predict that image through same lines of code that I have typed in the endpoint request handler file.
from model_config.model_handler import ModelConfig

model_config = ModelConfig("users/thushara2@gmail.com/automatic/characters.jpg")
pred = model_config.get_predictions()
print(pred)


I'm so confused by this error. I don't understand why it is complaining about cp1252 encoding on an image. I'm also unsure what the flask component is here because you're hard-coding the image location? So, it's the same image but purely because you've wrapped it in a flask route, you suddenly get this error?

In the beginning, I used that route to save the uploaded image in that location, and after prediction goes as well. But when I call that endpoint through my front end that error occurs.
However, this project was built from my older laptop with Python 3.9 and worked very well there. But, the problems occurred when I transferred the project to my new laptop with Python 3.12
